# paramiko - slow sftp transfer speed compared with system rsync/sftp/scp

Tags: python, paramiko

I have noticed that I can't get the same transfer speed when performing a get or put with paramiko's sftp.

Across our gigabit network from our mac mini server (running Mac os 10.12.6) a file transfer via rsync/sftp/scp/finder sustains around 95-100MB/sec. If I use paramiko's sftp.get I see it reaches a maximum of 25MB/sec.

I was using paramiko 1.17 and updated to 2.3.1 but am seeing pretty much the same speed.

Any ideas what could be causing the limitation?

Thanks!

Adam

Comment: Others have complained about this as well, already years ago. There are some possible solutions for example here https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/175 but not sure if it helps.

Comment: Hannu thanks for the link. I also found a few of these suggestions on GitHub and SO however none of the suggestions such as changing the window_size make any difference. Fingers crossed something comes up. Cheers

Comment: Hi @adamteale, any luck with this issue? I'm having the same issue, the window_size increase doesn't make any difference for me either, I also get max 25MB/s. I wanted to get the same speed as I get using scp, over 50MB/s. Did you manage to improve the speed using paramiko?

Comment: any luck so far, I am facing the same issues with the latest versions, but I do not see recent questions. am I alone?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and implemented a few suggestions that others made.  There are three things that can be done:

1. Increase the buffer size in your transport.

   ```
     transport = paramiko.Transport(ftp_host, ftp_port)
     transport.default_window_size = 4294967294 # 2147483647
     transport.packetizer.REKEY_BYTES = pow(2, 40)
     transport.packetizer.REKEY_PACKETS = pow(2, 40)
   ```
2. Perform a read ahead prior to getting the file.

   ```
    ftp_file = ftp_conn.file(file_name, "r")  
    ftp_file_size = ftp_file.stat().st_size 
    ftp_file.prefetch(ftp_file_size)
    ftp_file.set_pipelined()  
    ftp_file_data = ftp_file.read(ftp_file_size)
   ```
3. The other thing you can do when transferring larger files is implementing "chunks". This splits the files into smaller pieces that are transferred individually. I have only tested this with a transfer to s3.

   ```
    chunk_size = 6000000 #6 MB
    chunk_count = int(math.ceil(ftp_file_size / float(chunk_size)))
    multipart_upload = s3_conn.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_key_val)
    parts = []
    for i in range(chunk_count):
        print("Transferring chunk {}...".format(i + 1), "of ", chunk_count)

        start_time = time.time()
        ftp_file.prefetch(chunk_size * (i+1) # This statement is where the magic was to keep speeds high.
        chunk = ftp_file.read(int(chunk_size))
        part = s3_conn.upload_part(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=s3_file_path,
            PartNumber=part_number,
            UploadId=multipart_upload["UploadId"],
            Body=chunk
        )
        end_time = time.time()
        total_seconds = end_time - start_time
        print("speed is {} kb/s total seconds taken {}".format(math.ceil((int(chunk_size) / 1024) / total_seconds), total_seconds))
        part_output = {"PartNumber": i, "ETag": part["ETag"]}
        parts.append(part)
    print("Chunk {} Transferred Successfully!".format(i + 1))

    part_info = {"Parts": parts}
    s3_conn.complete_multipart_upload(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=s3_key_val,
        UploadId=multipart_upload["UploadId"],
        MultipartUpload=part_info
    )
   ```

The important part while processing the chunck is the  ftp_file.prefetch(chunk_size * (i+1)) which reads ahead incrementally further with each loop.

After implementing all of this, downloads went from 200 kBps to 5 MBps (the max tunnel speed).

In a later iteration of this code I ran into problems with the garbage collection from paramiko. I resolved them by removing the line:

```
ftp_file.set_pipelined()
```